# I get a NullPointerException when I invoke .equals() on a null String

Tags: android

I'm using 1 Activity for multi tasks depends on the intent i pass from the MainActivity. So if i pass "yes" it will show and hide some elements of the View, otherwise it will show the normal activity, but some times the app crash because of NullPointerExepction, and it leads me to the place where i call the intent String, like there's no String passed. So i'm wondring if it's because I'm useing a string instead of boolean or so. What would be the better method for my case? 
here what i'm using for now:

```
public String getUserStatus(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    isUserLogedin = intent.getExtras().getString("userstatus");
    return isUserLogedin ;
}
```

and i use this :
 `if(getUserStatus().equals("yes"))`

Comment: Can you put some code please? And logcat?

Comment: Looks like the result of `getExtras()` is probably null.  According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()), [`getExtras()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) returns null if no extra values were set.

Comment: @jahroy yes, while i'm sure the activity run with an Extras.

Comment: **Like codeMagic has already suggested**: replace `getUserStatus().equals("yes")` with `"yes".equals(getUserStatus())`.  That's a common trick used to avoid NPE in the exact situation that is causing yours.

Comment: @jahroy i have updated the question with the `Extras`, :) reading with fast eyes i didn't notice he using another method rather than mine. thank you.

Comment: @jahroy also thank you for the boolean trick `Boolean.TRUE.equals(someBool);`

Comment: @jahroy if you could upvoit the question it may help other people. Thank you.

Comment: @jahroy not going to argue about the downvote or so, it's the right of every member here. But i would rather change the title or the content of the question if that the reason of downvoting, and you have the right for that, anyway thank you and codeMagic.

Comment: I just removed the downvote... But I don't think this question is useful to others.  If you boil it down, this question is basically the equivalent of: "_I get a NullPointerException when I invoke `.equals()` on a null String_."  I don't think many people will find that enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code and logcat would be very helpful in this situation. However, I can say that if this `Activity` isn't always accepting a value in the `Intent` then if you do something like

```
if ("yes".equals(variableName))
```

it will protect against `null` values

because you won't get a `NPE` on the `String` "yes". You can try that. if it doesn't work then please post relevant code and logcat.

Comment: Yes it's the same method i use, i have updated my question. it's from google play `publish app` alot of users reported it.

Comment: You can do the same for Booleans like this: `Boolean.TRUE.equals(someBool);`

Comment: @Alamri - According to the code you posted in your question, you're **not** using the same approach.  Notice this answer suggests `"X".equals(y)` in stead of `y.equals("X")`.  There's a big difference.  Once might throw a NPE, the other will not.

Comment: You're welcome. Definitely a good trick but not sure about a pro ;)

Comment: @jahroy my start on Java was back to Blackberry 5 and that gave me a bad infrastructure. and nope, i could have used other method to call the String, but he got the way i used ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Boolean which will allow for a tristate:

true, false, not set.

Comment: Good point, i'm using String as "yes" or "no". but that looks stupid tho .. that why i'm asking this question :)